# Open Insert/edit link popup

Tags: tinymce, front-end, visual-editor

I'm using visual editor on front end. When clicking the Add/insert link button, it displays following

[image]

By clicking **Link options** icon, the following popup appears

[image]

**Is it possible to directly open the above popup by clicking on the Insert  link button from the editor?**

Comment: Hmm.. it used to be :P The inline popup was added in quite a recent version of WordPress.